# Why does my JS function only affect the first element addressed in the HTML structure? (changing display property of class)

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, if-statement

my basic structure of the JS function works. However, it only affects the first DIV in the HTML structure that is to be shown and hidden.

The CSS class "map-content" has `none` as display property. Several containers will receive this class and will therefore initially be hidden. All DIV containers get their own value, which is necessary in my code when changing the display property.

This is my function, which basically works, but only shows and hides the first container (in the HTML structure) with the "map-content" class.

```js
function validate_3() {
    
  var x = document.getElementById("location_select");
  var y = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
  var a = document.querySelector(".map-content");
  var b = a.getAttribute('value');
    
  {
    if (y == b) {
        a.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        a.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.map-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="location_select" onchange="validate_3">
  <option disabled selected>Select location...</option>
  <option value="de_germany">Berlin: Germany</option>
  <option value="fr_france">Paris: France</option>
  <option value="it_italy">Rome: Italy</option>
</select>

<div class="map-content" value="de_germany">
  <h3>This is Berlin</h3>
  <p>Berlin is in Germany</p>
</div>

<div class="map-content" value="fr_france">
  <h3>This is Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is in France</p>
</div>

<div class="map-content" value="it_italy">
  <h3>This is Rome</h3>
  <p>Rome is in Italy</p>
</div>
```

***Note on the code snippet:** I don't know why, but unlike my test interface, none of the selections work here. Not even the first in the structure as described in the text.*

I am happy to get general suggestions for a better structure if there are any.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): *"The Document method `querySelector()` **returns the first Element within the document** that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned."* So only the first element is affected because you are asking only for the first element. You want to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: And then you'll want to loop over the result.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the hint. I did not know that. Now i got to this point. I'm still doing something wrong:
 `var b = document.querySelectorAll(".map-content").forEach(function(element) {
    element.getAttribute('value');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a set of parentheses here `onchange="validate_3">` , add a set of parentheses  like this `onchange="validate_3()">`, and  your first selection should work

To get what you want, make sure you've added the parentheses as shown above.

javascript,

```
// take this line out of your funtion and change `querySelector` to
//`querySelectorAll`
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".map-content");

function validate_3() {
    
  var x = document.getElementById("location_select");
  var y = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;

//use The forEach() method to executes a provided function once for each
//element. 
  a.forEach((element) => {
  if (y != element.getAttribute("value")) {
  (element.classList.add("map-content"))
  } else {
  element.classList.remove("map-content")
  };
  });
};
```

But really, you're better off not using onclick at all and attaching the event handler to the DOM node through your Javascript code. This is known as [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion with the many comments. I am always very grateful for such comments in the code! I tested your code in my test interface and it works so far that the content is displayed, but the page has to be reloaded. If I then choose another location in the selection, the page has to be reloaded again to show the DIV with the "map-content" class. Any ideas what's causing this?

As requested, I have added the HTML and CSS to my original post.

Comment: I've updated my solution with your HTML code; please take a look at it and let me know if it works for you; thank you, I've tried it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abdzfw8g/1/)

Comment: Your updated solution seems to work and do what is requested. Before you posted the updated solution, I found one by changing your first code.

Comment: Yes, experiment with the code to make it work for you, gl.